# Change default size of terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Running uBuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run the Terminal, it always comes up in 80x24 mode. If I run my mouse over the title bar, a series of menu options appear. In the "Terminal" option, I can change to any of the following:

```
* 80x24
* 80x43
* 132x24
* 132x43
```

But when I close and re-open Terminal it reverts to 80x24 mode. How do I get Terminal to always start in 132x43 mode?

Comment: Do you want a command-line solution? Have you looked at 'man' page for Gnome Terminal? (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) Probably able to achieve by saving config. (**`--save-config=FILE`**), modifying the settings, and starting Gnome Terminal with this config. (**`--load-config=`**) ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changes in the menu are temporary. Use <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd> and change the settings in the dialog:

[image]

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for! My 14.04 LTS dialog is slightly different to the one shown, but the principle was the same. On the "General" tab I had to select "Use custom default terminal size" at the bottom and then set the columns and rows.