# Why does terminal always start in maximized mode?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In the process of working through some display issues causing DASH to behave poorly, I somehow caused terminal to always start in maximized mode.  How can I have it use the profile settings I had been using previously?  ie: not maximized nor full screened.

The issue was NOT as in the suggested duplicate question.  My issue was maximized terminal and not the rows and cols of the terminal screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default size of terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700901/change-default-size-of-terminal)

Comment: Not really a duplicate of the suggested question.  Some similar issues, but not quite.

Comment: Well, you have accepted the answer based on this Q&A, so...

Comment: Not the same.  I changed the rows and cols to be smaller than normal.  Then maximized.  Then restored.  Then set rows and cols to my preference.  At that point when opening terminal no longer opened maximized but did have my preferred rows and cols.

Comment: Then maybe write an expanded answer based on that suggestion and accept that instead.

Comment: Or use something like devilspie/gdevilspie.

Comment: Comments section is not a safe place for answers, they tend to disappear mysteriously! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700901/change-default-size-of-terminal).

If terminal is the only application that was affected, you may be able to fix it through terminal settings. Terminal > Preferences. Preferences > Profiles. There should be a Default Profile. Click "Edit" and on the general tab you can set the initial terminal size.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Not quite how I thought it would go, but you got me there.  I had to reset the "Initial Terminal Size" to something small and then set it to what I wanted.  It defaults to 80x24.  I preferred 120x36.  If I hit the reset button on the panel you recommended, then I can reset it to120x36 and it works.  Thank you much!